# Display fieldLabel in a container

Tags: javascript, extjs

All is in the question, I have a `DateField` and `Checkbox`. When I want to pool them in a container, `fieldLabel` disappear. How can I display fieldLabel? I'm using ExtJS 3.4

Here is my code :

```
var Dater = new Ext.form.DateField({
    fieldLabel: 'Effective Date : <span style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0); padding-left: 2px;">*</span>',
    name: 'date',
    format: 'd/m/Y',
    labelSeparator : '',
    id: 'date',
    width : 150
});

var imm = new Ext.form.Checkbox({
    fieldLabel: 'Effective immediately',
    cls: 'imm'
});

var dateCont = new Ext.Container({
    layout : 'column',
    items : [Dater, imm]
});
```

Comment: Post what you have done so far.

Comment: Which version of extjs are you using?

Comment: I forgot to add that detail you're right, I'm using extjs 3.4

Comment: Did you try adding only the `datefield` or only the `checkbox`?

Comment: Result is the same. Is there another way to put side by side those two items without a container? (cannot reach it with css method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try setting `layout:'form'` to individual column,

chechk [this](http://jsfiddle.net/77aZF/)

refer [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.Container)

Answer (score 2):

From the discussion above I think what you are missing are the `columnWidth` config. Try this:

```
var dateCont = new Ext.Container({
    layout : 'column',
    items : [
    {
    fieldLabel: 'Effective Date : <span style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0); padding-left: 2px;">*</span>',
    xtype: 'datefield',
    name: 'date',
    format: 'd/m/Y',
    labelSeparator : '',
    id: 'date',
    columnWidth : .5
},{
    xtype:'checkbox'
    fieldLabel: 'Effective immediately',
    cls: 'imm',
    columnWidth:.5
}]
});
```

Another way is to use a `Panel` with a `hbox` layout. This way, the items will be displayed one next to the other.

Comment: Here is what is going on with columnWidth : http://s21.postimg.org/4xvhqxtfr/Corporate_and_Business_News_Tool_Google_Chrome.jpg

Comment: Whoa, unexpected. Hmmm,try setting less for the `datefield`.